# Why is my zoom plot in shiny from ggplot2 blank

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a time series plot created in ggplot2 going to a panel in shinydashbaord. I need the bottom panel to be a zoom plot for the time series plot. For some reason, my zoom plot doesn't show the data or the axis values from the time series plot. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

The example below uses a date range that is set in the sidebar. If the date range is changed in this example, the plot won't work. My real work isn't that sensitive with the dates, this is just for demonstration.

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (ggplot2)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
 sidebarMenu(
   menuItem("Data Estimation", tabName = "tabset1",
      dateRangeInput("dates", 
                    "Date range for regression",
                    start = as.character(Sys.Date() - 495), 
                    end = as.character(Sys.Date() - 396))
)))

body <- dashboardBody(
 fluidRow(
  tabBox(id = "tabset1", height = "450px", width = "900px",
   tabPanel("Time Series Est", 
     plotOutput ("plot1", height = 400,
                 brush = brushOpts(
                   id = "plot1Brush",
                   resetOnNew = TRUE)))
)),
 fluidRow(
  tabBox(id = "tabset1", height = "450px", width = "900px",
   tabPanel("Zoom", 
     plotOutput ("plot2", height = 400)
))))

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) ({

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y = seq(1,2000,20), z = seq(1,3000,30), dateTime = seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], 1))

p <- ggplot() +
 geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = x, color = "x")) +
 geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = y, color = "y")) +
 geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = z, color = "z")) +
 scale_y_log10() +
 theme_bw()

print(p)

})

ranges2 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

observe({
 brush <- input$plot1Brush
 if (!is.null(brush)) {
  ranges2$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
  ranges2$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
}
else {
 ranges2$x <- NULL
 ranges2$y <- NULL
}
})


output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

if (!is.null(ranges2$x)) {
ranges2$x <- as.Date(ranges2$x, origin = "1970-01-01")
}

dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y = seq(1,2000,20), z = seq(1,3000,30), dateTime = seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], 1))

p <- ggplot() +
 geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = x, color = "x")) +
 geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = y, color = "y")) +
 geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = z, color = "z")) +
 coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges2$x, ylim = ranges2$y) +
 scale_y_log10() +
 theme_bw()

print(p)

})

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your renderPlot() expressions, instead of using `print(p)`, replace by `p`

it worked for me.

Comment: I think there is no difference between using `print(p)` and `p`. Did you see one? I didn't but I am never sure about these things.

Comment: actually yes, there is. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445367/r-shiny-datatableoutput-not-displaying-brushed-points

Comment: Interesting. Will look into that. Still I think he has just not noticed that when he changes the date his date vector is no longer 100 in length, which causes the plot to fail and come back blank.

Comment: I had posted in my original question that I am aware that if you change the date the plot will fail completely for this example. Try not changing the date.

Answer (score 0):

Your data sequence vectors are different lengths.

Replace your data frame definitions (both of them) with this:

```
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1,to=100,length.out=n), 
                  y = seq(1,to=2000,length.out=n), 
                  z = seq(1,to=3000,length.out=n), 
                  dateTime = seq(input$dates[1], to=input$dates[2],length.out=n))
```

I tested that and it worked fine. Before it errored and emitted a blank plot when I changed the date and the plot was blank. Which I believe is the problem?

Here is the complete code:

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (ggplot2)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Estimation", tabName = "tabset1",
             dateRangeInput("dates", 
                            "Date range for regression",
                            start = as.character(Sys.Date() - 495), 
                            end = as.character(Sys.Date() - 396))
    )))

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(id = "tabset1", height = "450px", width = "900px",
           tabPanel("Time Series Est", 
                    plotOutput ("plot1", height = 400,
                                brush = brushOpts(
                                  id = "plot1Brush",
                                  resetOnNew = TRUE)))
    )),
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(id = "tabset1", height = "450px", width = "900px",
           tabPanel("Zoom", 
                    plotOutput ("plot2", height = 400)
           ))))

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) ({

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

   # dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y = seq(1,2000,20), z = seq(1,3000,30), dateTime = seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], 1))
    n <- 100
    dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1,to=100,length.out=n), 
                      y = seq(1,to=2000,length.out=n), 
                      z = seq(1,to=3000,length.out=n), 
                      dateTime = seq(input$dates[1], to=input$dates[2],length.out=n))   
    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = x, color = "x")) +
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = y, color = "y")) +
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = z, color = "z")) +
      scale_y_log10() +
      theme_bw()
    p

  })

  ranges2 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  observe({
    brush <- input$plot1Brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges2$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges2$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
    }
    else {
      ranges2$x <- NULL
      ranges2$y <- NULL
    }
  })


  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    if (!is.null(ranges2$x)) {
      ranges2$x <- as.Date(ranges2$x, origin = "1970-01-01")
    }
    n <- 100
    dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1,to=100,length.out=n), 
                      y = seq(1,to=2000,length.out=n), 
                      z = seq(1,to=3000,length.out=n), 
                      dateTime = seq(input$dates[1], to=input$dates[2],length.out=n))

    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = x, color = "x")) +
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = y, color = "y")) +
      geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = dateTime, y = z, color = "z")) +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges2$x, ylim = ranges2$y) +
      scale_y_log10() +
      theme_bw()

    p

  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: 100/1=100, 2000/20=100,  3000/30=100, and the date range has 100 days. You haven't addressed the question and the vectors are all the same length. I tested that code before I posted it. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: Not after you change it. It emitted an error and the plot was blank then. Wasn't that the problem? Try and and you will see.

Comment: I tried your solution and when I zoom on the plot on the top, I still have a blank plot on the bottom. I never got an error message, just a blank plot. That was the original problem. The answer below fixed the problem. From you screenshot, it doesn't appear that you tried to zoom on the plot on top. The problem was that after zooming on the top, the plot on bottom was blank. However, I do appreciate the attempt. Thanks.

Comment: But you got an error message on the console, and that was why you have a blank plot.

Comment: I will post all my code. But I am not too fussed. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Note I have no problems changing the date, and I never get a blank plot either.

Comment: The original question stated that I am aware that if you change the date for this example, the plots will fail. You still haven't addressed the problem. Try using the original code and actually using the zoom on the top plot (without messing with the date first). Then try it with the solution below (without messing with the date). Thanks, though.

Comment: I see. I was confused by the fact that changing the date also causes the plot to go blank because your date range becomes the wrong length. Fixing that causes it to stick around. So it sounded like the root of your problem.

Comment: I never even noticed the zoom function :). Nice idea.